# How is rego(long) in English a cognate of rogo(long) in Latin?

Tags: etymology, english

Keller's Learn to Read Latin says that rego(long) in English is a cognate of rogo(long) in Latin. I found that rego(long)  in English means registration. How is it a cognate of rogo(long) in Latin? I can't find its etymology on etymology online.

Comment: I can almost guarantee it doesn't say that.

Comment: Yeah, you're misreading something.

Comment: On the page in question (322 in my edition), *rego* is in bold (unlike all the other clearly English words), and the *o* has a macron; both of which would seem to indicate that *rego* is in this case the Latin verb meaning 'to keep straight/guide/direct' and not the English word that means 'registration'. OLD does suggest that the Latin verbs *rogo* and *rego* are cognates, though others here can speak to that point better than I.

Answer (score 3):

*Regō* is not an English word, but a Latin one. English does not use macrons on vowels.

The English slang term "rego", short for "registration", ultimately goes back to Latin *re-gerō* rather than *regō*, but the former was almost certainly influenced by the latter.